# $BG$ and shifted symplectic structure in general

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, symplectic-geometry

I know that a $k$-shifted symplectic structure is a nondegenerate $\left[\left(\omega^0, \omega^1, \ldots\right)\right] \in H^k\left(\bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty} \bigwedge^{p+i} \mathbb{L}_{\boldsymbol{X}}[i], \mathrm{d}+\mathrm{d}_{d R}\right)$ where $p=2$.

Can you explain to me what is the $2$-shifted symplectic structure on $BG$? So far I have found only [image].

Also I've heard that one should interpret the higher terms $\omega^1,\omega^2,\dots$ to be some sort of nulhomotopy; can you elaborate on this (or any other intuition/examples) of the $k$-shifted symplectic structure? **I've had some reading and found out some of the intuition (see my answer below). There's still a minor question bolded in my answer.**

Also I’ve heard that $\operatorname{Map}(U,BG)$ has a regular symplectic structure for every U induced by the shifted one on $BG$. Can you elaborate a bit on this also?

Thanks.

Comment: What is BG ?....

Comment: @JeanMarie The quotient stack $[*/G]$.

Comment: @YaiOPhah Thanks to you. It would have been nice if Sayako consider my question as worth answering it, but apparently he/she doesn't want to enter into a dialog...

Comment: @JeanMarie I’m in a different timezone than you…lol

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess now I know at least for $BGL_n$, $\omega^0$ is given by $(A,B)\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ and I'll expand on this once I know more.

---

Update Sep 21:
Okay so I got some of the motivation and intuition now. I recommend anyone who's confused by PTVV as me to read Calaque https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09643.pdf. The terms $\omega^1,\omega^2,\dots$ are there to make the differential forms homotopy invariant. So here's a summary of what I'm no longer confused by:

1. There are these cosimplicial $\Delta^*_\text{inf}$ thing such that $\Delta^1_\text{inf}=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2)$.
2. To get $\operatorname{deRham}(X)$, you just do $\operatorname{DoldKan}(C^\infty(X^{\Delta^*_X}))$.
3. Obviously closed $p$-forms are $p$-cocycles in $\operatorname{deRham}(X)$, so you say they are also maps $\mathbb{R}[-p]\to\operatorname{deRham}(X)$ in the derived category, and furthermore you can unDoldKan on both side and get the same thing which is apparently the advertised way of doing it in Calaque.
4. For non-closed forms you do cosimplicial truncation.
5. Move to the abelian case we do resolution for $\operatorname{unDoldKan}(\mathbb{R}[-p])$, and we get the $(\omega^{0},\dots)$ such that $\omega^i$ is situated at weight (de Rham degree) $p+i$ and degree (cotangent complex degree) $n+i$ and $d_\text{dR}\omega^i=d_{\text{cot}}\omega^{i+1}$ and $d_\text{cot}\omega^0=0$.

The only point that I don't understand is that in
[image]
the de Rham differentials (the degeneracy maps) are going straight up but in
[image]
where they take the Dold-Kan alternating sum of degeneracy thing, it's going side ways. And apparently this is confirmed by a lot of people so it's unlikely that it's a mistake. **If you know about why please shed some light for me.** Thanks in advance.

Also on p.13 of Calaque, they definitely made a mistake by saying that $\alpha_i$ will be at degree $p+n$ if the $d_\text{dR}$ does go diagonally.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. there is a typo for the degree of $\alpha_i$ on p.13. It should be $i+n$.

Comment: @DamienC Dear Prof. Calaque, I'm sorry as this is definitely a stupid question (the detail of which I've forgotten). But I think d_dR is not a mere DK but also involves the \partial right? Thanks.